# How to boot into the Recovery mode without volume buttons and reset hole?

Tags: recovery-mode, tablet

I'm having a Chinese tablet Allwinner Quad Core A33. The tablet has only Power and Home buttons. No Volume buttons, no reset hole.

When it boots, it freezes on the Company logo.

The ADB devices command sees no devices.

I am trying to boot into the Recovery mode by holding down the Power and Home button, then releasing the Power button, but nothing happens (like pressing the Power and Volume Up buttons on other devices).

Is there any way to boot into the Recovery mode?

Comment: Nice tip for the future: before you buy a phone, always check its rootability on the Google. If you find such problems like yours, **boycott the whole manufacturer**.

Comment: try one of this to repair 1) [livesuit](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-livesuit) 2) [phoenix-suit](https://androidmtk.com/use-phoenix-suit-flash-firmware) 3) [phoenix-usb-pro](https://androidmtk.com/flash-stock-rom-using-phoenix-usb-pro) 4) [phoenixcard](https://androidmtk.com/use-phoenixcard-tool)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can go to the Download mode by pressing and holding down the Home button. Then I connect the USB and press the Power button. I also used Phoenix Suite.

Comment: Sorry, this site cannot help in finding external sites for firmware. Also, unlike traditional forums where posts are used to reply to each other, Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, thus answers can only be used to answer the question, not for asking further questions.